# ListView items don't load on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

The use case is the following:
I want to load a ListView inside a ViewPager and at the same time set a OnItemClickListener on the list.

Can someone tell why is that the ListView doesn't load, i.e. the screen stays black. Not even the strip from the pager works.

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dip" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**Some code:**

```
public static class HeaderFragment extends ListFragment {

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    String topic;

    public HeaderFragment(List<Message> messages, String topic) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public HeaderFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        final MessageItemAdapter adapter = new MessageItemAdapter(inflater,
                R.layout.headers, messages, 1);


        //the click listener.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Message message = adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName(
                        "main",
                        "NewsActivity");
                intent.putExtra("title", message.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("description", message.getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("source", message.getLink().toString());
                intent.putExtra("language", location);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
```

Thanks in advance !!!

EDIT:

The code that calls the fragment:

```
public class HeadersActivityPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public HeadersActivityPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        int k = 0;
        String topic = null;
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

        for (Entry<String, List<Message>> elem : fragmentsData.entrySet()) {
            if (k==i)
            {
                topic = elem.getKey();
                messages = elem.getValue();
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }

        return new HeaderFragment(messages, topic);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentsData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        int k = 0;
        String topic = "";
        for (Entry<String, List<Message>> elem : fragmentsData.entrySet()) {
            if (k==position)
            {
                topic = elem.getKey();
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return topic;
    }
}
```

It works like this, but i lose the listener for the ListView:

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dip" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

submain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Some code:

```
public static class HeaderFragment extends ListFragment {

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    String topic;

    public HeaderFragment(List<Message> messages, String topic) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public HeaderFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.submain, container, false);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        final MessageItemAdapter adapter = new MessageItemAdapter(inflater,
                R.layout.headers, messages, 1);


        //the click listener.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Message message = adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName(
                        "main",
                        "NewsActivity");
                intent.putExtra("title", message.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("description", message.getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("source", message.getLink().toString());
                intent.putExtra("language", location);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
```

The problem is that i lose my listener, doesn't trigger.
The solution i found slows the hell down my application.

I place the listener inside the adapter, for each item.

Comment: Since you're having it in a `ViewPager`, I assume there is other stuff you display in it. This stuff gets displayed properly? And also, please post the code of the `MessageItemAdapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewPager is set to height `0px`. Give it a larger height and you should be able to see it. Perhaps:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

**EDIT:**

Show the code where you are creating this fragment and adding it to the screen. Also add some logging to this constructor:

```
public HeaderFragment(List<Message> messages, String topic) {
    this.messages = messages;
    Log.i("TAG", "messages size: " + this.messages.size(); // <- add this
    this.topic = topic;
}
```

to ensure that `messages` has some items in it when it gets passed to here. This fragment never adds any items to `messages` so if it has none in it when you create the fragment then there won't be any to show in the ListView.

Comment: The problem persists. The Strip appears, but the ListView doesn't show any data...

Comment: post the code where you create the fragment, and see my edit.

Comment: Messages are not empty, that's for sure.

Comment: "`that's for sure.`" how can you be sure? You aren't logging it anywhere.

Comment: Because this code is refactored and i already debugged for that 2 minutes ago.

Comment: Believe me, messages is not empty.

Comment: I have a solution but i lose the listener i have in the ListView. See my edit.